# Calculating Number of possible solutions to large Integers

Tags: combinations, integers, law-of-large-numbers

I was looking for the best possible mean to determine all possible integer solution sets for large number such

21527411027188897018960152013128254292577735888456
75980170497676778133145218859135673011059773491059
60249790711158521430207931466520284014061994699492
7570407753

If you use an approach to finding all possible solution set using a format  such as x1*10^0+x2*10^1+x3*10^2.....x*10^160.
What would be the best approach to using to find all possible combinations.

Comment: How many choices are there for $X_3$? And by a fixed $X_3$ then how many are there for $X_2$?

Comment: Mention about your try.

Comment: I haven't tried as combinations and probability are not my field of expertise, I was looking for help to determine in a general way to bet approach to calculating the probability for this type of equation.  Ultimately i want to be able to add more terms to enable solving for much larger numbers with more variables

Answer (score 2):

### Hint

Note that for any choice of $x_3<8$ and $x_2<79-10x_3$ there is only one choice of $x_1$ that satisfies the equation.

So you need to count how many alternatives you have to choose $(x_2,x_3)$ that satisfy those constraints

Comment: so the number of choices would simply be the possible choices for x3  which would be the integers 0 through 9

Comment: more like $$\sum_{x_3=0}^{x_3=7}{(79-10x_3)}$$, please accept my answer if it was helpful